# 2 B static IP not working

Tags: networking, static-ip

I recently bought a Raspberry Pi 2B and was setting it up. I was told to make the IP static by changing the line

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

However, the IP config file did not contain the word `dhcp` anywhere. It looked something like this

```
 # Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
 Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Then I changed it to this:

```
 # Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
 address 192.168.1.121
 network 192.168.1.0
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 broadcast 192.168.1.255
 gateway 192.168.2.1

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
 Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I tried to change `manual` to `static`, but nothing worked. Can someone please tell me what to do?

Answer (score 1):

For a static ip configuration, change the line

```
iface eth0 inet manual
```

in `/etc/network/interfaces` to

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.97   
netmask 255.255.255.0  
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

For a dynamic ip configuration, use dhcp to automatically assign a ip adress to your raspberry pi and change the line to

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```